# Chart.js - How to create group stacked chart bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js, stacked-bar-chart

I have a few device names in my original data set. And there are also how many points a user has on each device. Now how do I want to show the number of users and points associated with each device in the bar/column of that device? I'm totally stacked and new in Chart.js, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Original data in console:

```
console.log(alldata)

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: 
    device: "Laptop"
    values: Array(2)
    0: {amckinlay: '30'}
    1: {cvu: '150'}
1: device: "Phone"
    values: Array(1)
    0: {amckinlay: '100'}
```

Dataset for chart:

```js
d1 = [
        {
            label: 'amckinlay',
            data: [30],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        },
        {
            label: 'cvu',
            data: [150],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        }
    ]
d2 =[
        {
            label: 'amckinlay',
            data: [30],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        }
    ]

var dataset = {
    labels: ['Laptop', 'Phone'],
    datasets: [d1,d2]
};
```

The chart looks like [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/3aDAvdFqFE1J9jSx7)

```js
var alldata = data.data
var datasets = [];
var labels = [];

for (var i = 0; i < alldata.length; i++) {
    labels.push(alldata[i].device)
    for (var group in labels) {
        if (labels[group] === alldata[i].device) {
            console.log(alldata[i].values)
            // var val =alldata[i].values
        }
    }

datasets.push({
    label: [],
    data: alldata[i].values,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

1. x-axis label should be the `device`.
2. The dataset in which each item's label should be the category such as "amckinlay", "cvu" etc. And each item's data contains the value according to the `device`.

The problem is your data `values` from `alldata` which is key-value pair makes it difficult to extract the key. Would recommend converting it into the form:

```
{ "category": "amckinlay", "value": 100 }
```

```js
var colorSettings = [
  {
    category: 'amckinlay',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
  },
  {
    category: 'cvu',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
  },
];

var labels = alldata.map((x) => x.device);
alldata = alldata
  .map((x) =>
    x.values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      for (let k in cur) {
        acc.push({
          device: x.device,
          category: k,
          value: cur[k],
        });
      }

      return acc;
    }, [])
  )
  .flat();

var subLabels = [...new Set(alldata.map((x) => x.category))];

var datasets = subLabels.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  for (let device of labels) {
    var value =
      alldata.find((x) => x.device == device && x.category == cur)?.value ??
      0;

    var category = acc.find((x) => x.label == cur);
    if (category == null) {
      acc.push({
        label: cur,
        data: [value],
        backgroundColor: colorSettings.find((x) => x.category == cur)
          .backgroundColor,
      });
    } else {
      category.data.push(value);
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Note that, your chart configuration `options` should have the stacked setting as mentioned in the [Stacked bar chart documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets,
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zy9ueq?file=index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Since it is a dynamic dataset, I checked by changing the dataset. It doesn't work properly on two different datasets. `Index1` and `Index2` are given in the `HTML` file. If you please check the link. I will be very benefited and grateful.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gzp295?file=index.html,index1.html

Comment: Hi @AbzalAli, ya I also found out that the weakness of previous code, I amend the answer. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zy9ueq?file=index.html)